# Site com rolagem horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bom, tenho que fazer um site como scroll horizontal com [este](https://www.grandimage.com/),(o site que passei é somente para exemplificar a rolagem, não os efeitos) porém não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer, dei uma boa pesquisada antes de fazer a pergunta aqui.

Como eu sei que não é um assunto fácil para "ajudar/ensinar" gostaria que me ajudassem com pelo menos uma ideia de como fazer. Tenho conhecimento médio/avançado em html/css e js. Porém nunca fiz um site assim.

Espero que me ajudem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradeço! Acabei conseguindo!

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  font-family:Georgia;
}
#container .box {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
#container .box > div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  font-size:96px;
  color:#FFF;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
  line-height:.7;
  font-weight:bold;
}
#container {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-color:#999;
  position:absolute;
  width:100vh;
  height:100vw;
}
#container2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0;
}

.primeiro {
  background-color: #45CCFF;
}
.segundo {
  background-color: #49E83E;
}
.terceiro {
  background-color: #EDDE05;
}
.quarto {
  background-color: #E84B30;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="container2">
    <div class="box primeiro"><div>1</div></div>
    <div class="box segundo"><div>2</div></div>
    <div class="box terceiro"><div>3</div></div>
    <div class="box quarto"><div>4</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```